# Sort method in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I wrote method, to sort array of user inputs(integers) from low to high and reverse. Code looks like:

```
 def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
   arr.sort!
   if rev==true
     arr.reverse!
   end
   return arr 
 end

puts "enter your numbers with 'space' between them"
text = gets.chomp
numbers = text.split(" ")

numbers.each do |element|
  element.to_i
end
puts alphabetize(numbers)
```

First time i tried only numbers from 0 to 9, and method had worked correct. But then i tried to input numbers like 1112, 11, 22 and after sorting procedure, i had got result like this "11 1112 22". After this, i tried to change code this way:

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
  arr.sort!{|a, b| a.to_i <=> b.to_i}
  if rev==true
    arr.reverse!
  end
  return arr 
end

puts "enter your numbers with 'space' between them"
text = gets.chomp
numbers = text.split(" ")
puts alphabetize(numbers)
```

And this way my code works correct and sorting input of 11, 1112, 22 produce the result that i expect: "11, 22, 1112". Looks like i have solved the problem, but i really want to understand the difference between first version and second version of code. Why method sort works in different ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in the first place you still comparing strings instead of integers.

In fact, in the first place you don't convert elements to integers:

```
numbers.each do |element|
  element.to_i
end
```

The script below don't replace strings with integers in array.

Comment: but why? I thought, that "each" with "to_i" will convert every element of my array to integer, am i wrong?

Comment: The method is right but with each you just take every element and convert it, but no substitution is doing

Comment: You should have proposed the correction also, so that your answer would have got accepted.  I know that you answered first.  +1 for the effort.

Answer (score 3):

[`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) does not replace the elements in an array - it simply returns the array itself (without change).

You might prefer to use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
numbers = numbers.map  do |element|
  element.to_i
end
```

Or, better yet, use [`map!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21), which actually changes the array itself, rather than return the changed array:

```
numbers.map! do |element|
  element.to_i
end
```

You can also use the following shorthand:

```
numbers.map! &:to_i
```